# Bootstrap navbar doesn't collapse on small screen device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap `.navbar` doesn't collapse. It is responsive. When I see the website in this coding in small device. Then what it does is it makes the navbar small ad vertical but it doesn't collapse every page just stay on the screen. I tried to search online but their codes are little different then this one. Please check and tell me where i made mistake. thank you so much.

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Tweakwebs | Web Design And Development" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#disclaimers">Disclaimers</a></li> 
              </ul>
            </div>
              <div class="nav navbar-btn navbar-right">
                <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</button>
                <button class="signupbtn btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Signup</button>
              </div>
          </div>

        </nav>
    </div><!-- end of container -->
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few things: `collapse` and `navbar-toggle`. See example.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Tweakwebs | Web Design And Development" />
          </a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#service">Service</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#disclaimers">Disclaimers</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav navbar-btn navbar-right">
          <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</button>
          <button class="signupbtn btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Signup</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- end of container -->
</header>
```

Comment: It worked thank you...i did it and if you can then please check my site [tweakwebs](http://tweakwebs.com) and please tell me whether it is secured or not because i feel it's not secured coz db_connect.php doesn't have any security it is just there in the root directory..please check and tell me whether it's secured or not